# Translating logical to physical addresses for a virtual address

Tags: c++, c, virtual-address-space

I am currently working on a project to translate logical addresses to physical addresses. The question asks:

> This project consist of writing a program that translates logical to physical addresses for a virtual
>   address space of 2^16 = 65,536 bytes. Your program will read from a file containing logical
>   addresses and, using a TLB as well as a page table, will translate each logical address to its
>   corresponding physical address and output the value of the byte stored at the translated physical
>   address. Make sure your program uses fast operations like left/right shift operators.
>
> Specifics: Your program will read a file containing several 32-bit
>   integer numbers that represent logical addresses. However, you need
>   only be concerned with 16-bit addresses, so you must mask the
>   rightmost 16 bits of each logical address. These 16 bits are divided
>   into (1) an 8-bit page number and (2) 8-bit page offset

I've done some research and I've developed the following code, however, I know I'm not shifting the page and offet the correct amount of bits. I was given some sample I/O and currently my code is shooting out the wrong answers. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: SAMPLE I/O

> ```
>   Virtual address: 16916 Physical address: 20
>   Virtual address: 62493 Physical address: 285
>   Virtual address: 30198 Physical address: 758
> ```

```
#define MASK_BITS(x) ((x) & (unsigned int)0x0000FFFF)
unsigned long long int MapAddress(unsigned long long int address){
    unsigned long long int page = MASK_BITS(address);
    unsigned long long int offset = MASK_BITS(address);

    printf("The mapped address %llu contains:\n", address);

    page = page >> 13;
    printf("Page Number : %llu\n", page);

    offset = offset & 0x1FFF;

    printf("Offset = %llu\n\n", offset);
    return 0;
}
void myFunction()
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("/PATH/TO/addresses.txt", "r");
    char buffer[32];
    unsigned long long int x;
    int cnt = 1;
    while(!feof(fp)){
        fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer);
        x = atol(buffer);
        MapAddress(x);
        cnt++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return;
}
```

Comment: The problem statement says that page and offset are each 8 bits. Why are you shifting by 13 bits?

Comment: Not related to your masking problem, but: [why while(!feof(fp)) is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: Can you provide some example input and what you expect as output (by hand)?

Comment: @jojonas I added some sample I/O.

Comment: @Barmar I wasn't sure how many I should be shifting to be quite honest. As for the while(!feof(fp)) it is for the addresses I'm reading from a file.

Comment: I know what it's for. It's still wrong, as explained in that question.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions say that the address is split into 8-bit page and offset, but your code is using 13 bits instead of 8 bits. You need to shift by 8 bites to get the page number, and mask the lower 8 bits to get the offset.

```
unsigned long long int MapAddress(unsigned long long int address){
    address = MASK_BITS(address);

    printf("The mapped address %llu contains:\n", address);

    unsigned long long int page = address >> 8;
    printf("Page Number : %llu\n", page);

    unsigned long long int offset = address & 0xFF;

    printf("Offset = %llu\n\n", offset);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I edited the code to what you suggested, but, unfortunately, it still isn't providing the correct results. I've added some sample I/O to the question to help make things more clear.

Comment: The sample output you showed doesn't have the page number and offset. How do you know this code is wrong?